# Development workflow for a single-page app with PHP and Grunt

Tags: php, single-page-application, yeoman, gruntjs

I want my PHP single-page application to be friendly both to search engines and no-js browsers, so following [this Addy Osmani's article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/), I think I should write a php version of my index.html page that can respond to url parameters.

To the best of my knowledge, my index.php should be something like a tweaked version of the resulting dist/index.html after building with Grunt, to which I would add my php code. However, I find this to be not a very DRY approach, since it would involve manually editing my index.php (or whatever other filename I choose for it) every time I make changes to index.html.

I am sure there must be some other way, maybe obvious, to handle this in a Grunt/Yeoman workflow but I just can't figure out now and I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1):

I usually design the website as if it was a multi-page website,

and later on I use ajax-loading to convert it to be a single-page.

The ajaxify JQuery plugin is a good way to do it fast:

http://www.swook.net/p/jquery-ajaxify-plugin.html

Advantages: SEO won't be harmed, Search engines will follow the links.

Comment: +1 because it seems an interesting option for transforming a legacy multi-page app into a single-page app. However, I am oriented to "single-page first" and the use of javascript MVC frameworks, which I believe won't fit well with the Ajaxify approach.